# Is there a way to create a text file using a string name in C#

Tags: c#, string, text-files, filestream, streamwriter

I'm not sure if it's possible. I usually create txt files like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\textFile.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

but instead of using "c:\textFile.txt" I want to create a file using a string name. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to prompt the user for a file name, or what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Unsure what you mean... are you talking about this: `new FileStream(myVariable, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)`;

Comment: What's a "string name"?

Comment: Well I'm actually using this in a form application. I have a textBox, and whatever the user inserts into that textBox, I want to create a file from it.

Comment: Did you even check what parameters does the FileStream constructor take to ask that kind of questions?

Answer (score 5):

Of course. The first argument to the `FileStream` constructor takes a [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You've just passed it a string literal (defined in your source code file). It sounds like you want to pass a string variable instead:

```
string path = // get string from somewhere. A file save dialog, maybe?
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

May I suggest that you spend some time with a C# tutorial? Microsoft has some good [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/67ef8sbd.aspx) and [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). With all due respect, and we were all there once, you've got some holes in your knowledge that will trip you up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm following what you're asking for. You just asked if u could do that:

```
string filename = "c:\\textFile.txt";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

or as you specified

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(YourTextBox.Text, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```